# GCM getting duplicate messages but no canonical ID is returned

Tags: android, .net, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an app (is not deployed yet) and I've started to get duplicated GCM messages. I've read this could happen if, for some reason, the device is registered twice. So, I also read, that when this happens, the response after sending a message would include a canonical ID which I have to use to replace the previous registration ID.

So, the question is, I can't find the canonical ID.

This is how my server receives the response:

```
        'postData is a string with the request
        byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
        resp = CType(tRequest.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
        sr = New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream)
        respData = sr.ReadToEnd
        If (resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK) Then
            If respData.StartsWith("id=") Then
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("OK!")
```

So; I get the "OK" message (once), the message arrives to the device (twice), but I can't find the canonical ID on the respData (a string). Respdata has something like this:

```
 id=0:1432782509079127%4c1df638f9fd7dcd
```

So, where is the canonical ID?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you print out the entire response data from both messages?

Comment: Hi Koh. thank you very much for your answer! I send only one message, android receive it twice. So, I only get one respData per message. The entire respData value is the string I've posted (with some number and letters changed)

Comment: One thing you could try is call unregister on your gcm instance (not recommended for doing all the time). While unregistered, send a message to the device so that it will bounce back, informing the GCM server that your gcm instance has indeed been unregistered. Wait a few minutes and then re-register again by calling register. Save the new registration ID and replace the old one. Hopefully this will fix your issue. I've seen other people setting up new projects (and using the new project numbers as the new sender IDs), which you can try as well.

Comment: Hi Koh, thanks for your answer, again! I'll try as you say but I don't like "patching" particular cases or changing projects number in order to solve a problem. None of the two solutions are affordable once the app is deployed on thousands clients... I was looking for some "management" of the problem, some exceptional case I could manage within code (like getting the canonical ID and replacing it for the old one). I've been having issues with GCM in the 2 months I'm using it, I'm founding it very unreliable, I think I will give it one or two more chances before switch to another solution. Tky!

Comment: Hi Leo, good luck. I haven't had any serious issues with GCM the entire time that I've been using it, so I hope it works for you.

Comment: Hi Koh, thanks for your patience, but after resuming this project a few weeks ago, and after deleting the google project an building a new one, verifiying with one device that I'm registering only once and still getting the message twice, I'm moving away from GCM. I advice people with similar problems to do the same; I spent weeks trying to fix it and I regret that a lot.